# Laravel form validation wrong when using checkbox to hide/show fields causes

Tags: forms, validation, show-hide, laravel-6

I have a form in Laravel 6 that uses a checkbox to hide/show additional fields. So the fields are hidden, but when the user checks the box ('attorney') and the fields appear, they are required. Otherwise, when they are hidden (checkbox unchecked) they are not required.

The following are the validation rules for the form:

```
public function rules()

    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'role' => 'required',
            'role.*' => 'exists:roles,id',
            'attorney' => 'nullable',
            'bar_number' => 'nullable|required_if:attorney,1',
            'law_firm_email' => 'nullable|required_if:attorney,1',
            'law_firm_address' => 'nullable|required_if:attorney,1',
            'law_firm_name' => 'nullable|required_if:attorney,1',
        ];
    }
```

This hide/unhide works fine for users who check the box, and the form works for those that submit that extra info, but for those that don't check the box (those extra fields remain hidden) the form fails with the error "`The bar number must be a string`" (bar number is first field in list). The hidden fields are still being validated even though the checkbox is unchecked (the condition `required_if` should be false). I have tried '`checked`' and '`on`' for the checkbox value, same result.

This is the checkbox in the view:

```
<div class="col-md-6"></br>
                                <input id="attorney" type="checkbox" name="attorney" value="{{ old('attorney') }}"> Check if registering a law firm

                                @if ($errors->has('attorney'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('attorney') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
```

This is the JavaScript that hides/shoes the DIV with the additional fields:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[name="attorney"]').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('#bar_number_div').fadeIn('fast');
        } else {
            $('#bar_number_div').fadeOut('fast');
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The JavaScript works fine as expected. The validation config is my issue.

There are no errors in the console.

I thought the `required_if` condition in the validation rules should work as expected, i.e., when the checkbox "`attorney`" is unchecked the required validation rule is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with `on` in required_if**

```
public function rules() {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'role' => 'required',
            'role.*' => 'exists:roles,id',
            'attorney' => 'nullable',
            'bar_number' => 'nullable|required_if:attorney,on',
            'bar_number' => 'nullable|required_if:attorney,on',
            'law_firm_email' => 'nullable|required_if:attorney,on',
            'law_firm_address' => 'nullable|required_if:attorney,on',
            'law_firm_name' => 'nullable|required_if:attorney,on',
        ];
    }
```

> Remove `value` from input checkbox

```
<input id="attorney" type="checkbox" name="attorney">
```